# How do I add a variable inside single quotes which are inside muliti-line quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I define and populate a variable called: schema_prefix

```
if ENV == 'dev':
    schema_prefix = 'dev_'
if ENV == 'prod':
    schema_prefix = 'prod_'
```

Later I want to prepend that variable in a sql query string to the schema name contained in single quotes which is all wrapped in multi-line (triple quotes):

```
create_table_query = '''
                IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'smart_auto_diary_agent')) 
                BEGIN
                    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA smart_auto_diary_agent')
                END
                '''
```

So it should then look like this:

```
create_table_query = '''
                IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'dev_smart_auto_diary_agent')) 
                BEGIN
                    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA dev_smart_auto_diary_agent')
                END
                '''
```

How do I do this?

Comment: f-strings support triple quotes. `f''' ... name = '{prefix}smart_auto_diary_agent' ... '''`

Comment: You do it the same way as with single-line strings: Use `+` concatenation, f-strings, `.format()`, or `%`.